# How to use WSDL

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a WSDL application. But actually I didn't understand what makes the "?wsdl" parameter and what will I do with the returned XML. For example:

https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309/CampaignService?wsdl

This URL returns and XML string but what will I do with this?

I can convert schema files to java classes using jaxb (xjc) but I didn't understand correctly how to use this WSDL?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: First, do you know what a WSDL is and what it's for?

Comment: Probably it defines the web service rules.

Comment: Exactly. So once you know the rules, you can use the system. That's what the WSDL provides. The file you get form the URL in your question describes all the operations you can perform on that web service.

Comment: See if the following helps: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/wsdl/index.html

Comment: I understand this but where will I use it? Only checking truth of input-output of data?

Comment: I suggest you to write a simple web service (both server and client) and get an understanding of the concept. Such a detailed tutorial is found here at http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/web-service-axis-tutorial-client-server.html

Answer (score 2):

WSDL(Web Services Description Language) is just a contract in the form of xml defining the web services. It contains the details of input and output params of webservices. It is used between client and server to define the interface of communication. It is analogous to a method signature in a programming language. But as it is used between hetrogenous systems so xml is used to describe it.

Comment: Must I use this for checking truth of every input-output xml?

Comment: @kodmanyagha You can check wsdl for understanding the web services. Almost all the programming languages provide frameworks to read wsdls and generate client stubs, which are easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is a XML file which contains description of a SOAP web service. WSDL file contains details regarding XML request structure, XML response structure, Web service endpoint details, Web service URL etc.WSDL file is the single most important file of a SOAP web service. The owner of a web service provides [WSDL](http://www.tutorialscorner.com/webservice/WSDL.html) file to the client and by using the WSDL file a client interacts with the service. By using the WSDL file a client can generate client side stubs and java classes to contact with the server. Java since its release 7 supports APIs to generate client side code from a WSDL file. WSDL is created at the time of creating the web service.

When you have that URL containing the WSDL,simply use a tool like SOAPUI and generate a SOAP message and invoke web service. Web service can contain one more input elements so in that case you need to provide input element in the SOAP message.

To invoke a web service you just need a WSDL URL , you already have that. Just use a tool like SOAPUI.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is the file describing your webservices.

Meta Information about your methods, etc.
Any Web Client should understand and use WSDL files to generates all methods needed to communicate with a Web Server.